Net adapters both get up, but no internet connection made
I think I screwed it up when tried to install Network Manager over networkd running service. I have Ubuntu server installed on a brand new Raspberry PI 4 with only 1GB of ram, hence 'server'...
Much of the answers seen around are for Network Manager which is installed on desktops.
Uninstalling Network Manager didn't work. I think I did it. Hard to be sure.
Both interfaces, eth0 and wlan0 show same behavior. Up with IP address and all, but no internet connection .
netplan status shows both IP address and default route assigned.
Ping success over local phone or router.
---> PING SUCCESS TO UBUNTU.COM. OR GGL.<---
Any thoughts?
Edit:
$ apt policy network-manager
network-manager:
  Installed: none
  Candidate: 1.44.2-1ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
     1.44.2-1ubuntu1.2 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic-updates/main arm64 Packages
     1.44.2-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic/main arm64 Packages


$ sudo cat 50-cloud-init.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: true
      routes:
        -to: default
         via: 192.168.100.1
         metric: 100
   wifis:
     wlan0:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        [my-ssid]:
           password: [password]        


user@host~$ ip a
1: lo:
2: eth0:
3: wlan0:
    inet 192.168.220.73 metric 600 brd 192.168.220.255 scope global dynamic wlan0 valid_lt 2730sec preferred_lft 2730sec
inet6 fe80::


user@host~$ ip route
default via 192.168.220.124 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.220.73 metric 600
192.168.220.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope src 192.168.220.73 metric 600
192.168.220.124 dev wlan0 proto  scope src 192.168.220.73 metric 600


user@host~$ netplan status
Online state: offline
DNS Adressess: 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.1
1: lo unmanaged 

3: wlan0 wifi/[my-ssid] UP  networkd: wlan0 
Mac address:
Addresses: 192.168.220.73/24 dhcp fe80::
Routes: default via: and the same


Using Linux rpi 6.5.0-1020-raspi#23-Ubuntu.
resolv.conf file missing. Then I create it, same result.

$ resolvectl status
Failed to get global data: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found


$ ls -l resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- l root 57 nov 9 05:45 resolv.conf


No connection to "where" ? Not clear what the problem is. (update your question, don't add comments).

mpboden, yes, that's true, static route and dhcp, but same trouble with wlan0 as well..

user@host netplan
online status: offline
DNS Adressess:  8.8.8.8
8.8.8.1
1: lo unmanaged
3: wlan0 wifi/ networkd: wlan0
Mac address:
Addresses: 192.168.220.73/24 dhcp
fe80::
Routes: default via: and the same ...

code user@host:/etc$ resolvectl status
Failed to get global data: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.
code

code user@host:/etc$ ls -l resolv.conf code
code  -rw-r--r-- l root 57 nov 9 05:45 resolv.conf code

Do not add Solved or the answer to your original question. If you found a solution, add an actual answer and mark the checkbox that this is the answer.

@JohnnyApoliyo As mpboden said above, an answer in Ask Ubuntu should be posted as an answer and not inside the question. I have edited your question to remove the answer from it and have posted it as a separate answer in the form of a Community Wiki (CW) so I won't earn any points from it. If you want to post the question yourself, feel free to do so. I have followed your question so I will get notified if you post your answer. In that case I will delete the CW. Thanks!

You show the output of resolvectl status as:
Failed to get global data: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found

This indicates that systemd-resolved is not running.
Additionally, the output of ls -l /etc/resolv.conf indicates that it's a static file and not a symlink to /etc/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf, which would be the default setup. You don't list the contents of this file nor why this has been changed.
To solve your issue, first delete /etc/resolv.conf:
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf

Enable systemd-resolved:
sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved

Then start systemd-resolved:
sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved

Doing this will automatically create the symlink from /etc/resolv.conf to /etc/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf.


Oh nevermind, just needed to systemctl start systemd-resolved.service and
systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service.
Never had to do that before. Don't mind me.
From: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=288227

Answer moved here from OP's question.
